# Spring and Hibernate For DataBase

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, javabeans

I'm wondering if someone can steer me in the right direction.

I'm looking to create a database of SKU items.

I'm currently studying Spring using beans. I have now realised there is a few ways of doing this, either with a CSV file, using JDBC, Hibernate, XML, mySQL etc. I obviously want to use the most efficient way and one that would be the best practice and just wanted peoples thoughts on each of these processes.

Many thanks.

Comment: You are asking for an entire tutorial/textbook and discussion on writing a web application.  That is not the purpose of this site, and the question is off-topic as (much) "too broad".  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details and to learn how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see why this question is a problem. If you read my question, I only wanted peoples thoughts on what they prefer to use. I'm going to create the program no matter what choice I make. I don't want a tutorial...only what the preference is and the reason why.

Comment: _"I only wanted peoples thoughts on what they prefer to use"_ -- If you'd read the site guidelines you'd find that this is explicitly off-topic.  StackOverflow is not a discussion/opinion site.  Again, please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense anyway. You're looking for "the most efficient way", but are considering storing things in an XML or CSV file. Either the number of items and of concurrent users is so small that these are valid options, but then everything will be efficient enough, or you actually intend to have concurrent users and a large number of items, and a database is pretty much mandatory. Hibernate and JDBC are not databases. They are APIs to access a relational database. MySQL is a relational database. So you're comparing apples with oranges.